# Android FC report: interface not implemented

Tags: android, exception

Just received the below crash report on the Android dev console, however it doesn't hit my code and reports doesn't show Android version:

Checked source code for 4.1.x and 4.0.x, line 345 is this and length() is defined in an interface:
   return getText().length();

How could this actually be missing? I'm assuming I've used a setText() on something and it's not ok, but do I investigate, while I've no clue where it's actually happening!?

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: interface not implemented
at android.text.BoringLayout.getLineStart(BoringLayout.java:345)
at android.text.Layout.drawText(Layout.java:229)
at android.text.Layout.draw(Layout.java:205)
at android.text.BoringLayout.draw(BoringLayout.java:400)
at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4886)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13470)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13354)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13352)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13352)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13575)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1569)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13354)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13352)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13352)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13352)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13473)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2185)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:2258)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2153)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2021)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1832)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4899)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could possibly be due to change in library that android.text.BoringLayout is a part of. May be the interfaces that class implements have changed it's method signature or have added new methods or have changed it's accessibility rights (public protected private).

The devices this might be happening on may be hosting custom roms developed by independent users with different definitions given to one of the interfaces implemented by BinaryLayout or one of it's superclasses.

A backward binary compatibility case

Comment: That's the only answer I could come up with to explain this.